# 'replacing a task' gradle deprecation warning with javafx on intellij

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I am trying to create a project on Gradle in IntelliJ and use JavaFX on it.

I added --module-path ${PATH_TO_FX} --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml as openjfx suggested and applied changes to build.gradle as they suggested.

when I run I get a deprecation warning stating:

```
Unnecessarily replacing a task that does not exist has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 6.0. Try using create() or register() directly instead. You attempted to replace a task named 'Main.main()', but no task exists with that name already.
    at Main_main___7am0b7lhc2gbw0z3kepxi13tt$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(C:\Users\MirAdnan\AppData\Local\Temp\Main_main__.gradle:18)
```

And this is the temp file generated when I run:

```
def gradlePath = ':'
    def runAppTaskName = 'Main.main()'
    def mainClass = 'Main'
    def javaExePath = 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-12.0.1/bin/java.exe'
    def _workingDir = 'C:/Users/MirAdnan/IdeaProjects/animation'

    def sourceSetName = 'main'
    def javaModuleName = null





    allprojects {
      afterEvaluate { project ->
        if(project.path == gradlePath && project?.convention?.findPlugin(JavaPluginConvention)) {
          project.tasks.create(name: runAppTaskName, overwrite: true, type: JavaExec) {
            if (javaExePath) executable = javaExePath
            classpath = project.sourceSets[sourceSetName].runtimeClasspath
            main = mainClass
            jvmArgs '--module-path'
jvmArgs 'C:/Program Files/Java/javafx-sdk-12.0.1'
jvmArgs '--add-modules'
jvmArgs 'javafx.controls,javafx.fxml'
jvmArgs '--module-path'
jvmArgs 'C:/Program Files/Java/javafx-sdk-12.0.1'
jvmArgs '--add-modules'
jvmArgs 'javafx.controls,javafx.fxml'

            if(_workingDir) workingDir = _workingDir
            standardInput = System.in
            if(javaModuleName) {
              inputs.property('moduleName', javaModuleName)
              doFirst {
                jvmArgs += [
                  '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                  '--module', javaModuleName + '/' + mainClass
                ]
                classpath = files()
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

here is the build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

javafx {
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}
```

I only have one class file and I don't think it is the problem:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(Main.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

        //top
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        Menu exit = new Menu("exit");
        menuBar.setUseSystemMenuBar(true);
        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(exit);
        pane.setTop(menuBar);

        //Scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600, Color.BLACK);

        //Stage
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

The app does execute without any error but this deprecation warning is bugging me and I would try to fix it if I knew what caused it

Comment: If you use the JavaFX gradle plugin, you don't have to add `--module-path ${PATH_TO_FX} --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`. I don't see `mainClassName` in your build.

Comment: if i dont use the vm line i get the javafx.controls not found error

Comment: gonna add the mainClassName now thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

This is known bug:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-224030

and it should be fixed in some of upcoming versions.