# How to fix Error: Unnecessarily replacing a task that does not exist has been deprecated

Tags: java, android-studio

I am new to learning java, and believe I am missing a step somewhere. I am simply trying to output "Hello World" in android studio.

I am taking an online class through udemy, and this has halted me completely. I even did a complete PC wipe to ensure none of my settings were screwing anything up.

```
package com.example.learnjava;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Expecting the output "Hello World" in the console, instead get the following error:

> 11:20:01 PM: Executing task 'HelloWorld.main()'...
>
> Executing tasks: [HelloWorld.main()] in project C:\Users\phuiz\AndroidStudioProjects\LearnJava
>
> Configure project :app
>   Unnecessarily replacing a task that does not exist has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 6.0. Try using create() or register() directly instead. You attempted to replace a task named 'HelloWorld.main()', but no task exists with that name already.
>       at HelloWorld_main___8g5slkzupty1xjavpsz1qxha8$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(C:\Users\phuiz\AppData\Local\Temp\HelloWorld_main__.gradle:18)
>       (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>     Initialization script 'C:\Users\phuiz\AppData\Local\Temp\HelloWorld_main__.gradle' line: 20
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>     Could not create task ':app:HelloWorld.main()'.
>     SourceSet with name 'main' not found.
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 0s
>   11:20:01 PM: Task execution finished 'HelloWorld.main()'.

Comment: push!
got the same annoying problem. new android studio project, new java module, simple hello world and same problem:
Unnecessarily replacing a task that does not exist has been deprecated.

Comment: Android Studio is a version of IntelliJ IDEA. Looks like your issue could be the same as this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57715947/replacing-a-task-gradle-deprecation-warning-with-javafx-on-intellij/58669638#58669638

Answer (score 4):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/11371#issuecomment-554553932).

To fix it, just upgrade your IntelliJ version to 2019.3 or newer.